# Using GIT between local sites

Tags: linux, git

I cloned a Git repository to recreate a website in my localhost DEV environment. Later I created a second copy of the site, STAGING, by copying the code base from the first, DEV, site. The staging site has no .git file.

Recently, I've decided to stop coping and pasting from DEV to STAGING. But, how do I initialize Git on STAGING so I can pull changes from DEV?

I tried executing the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin /var/www/DEV-SITE
git pull
```

All those commands worked but when I execute `git branch` or `git log`, there are no branches nor any log entries.

**Update:**

Following @cassm, I encounter the following issue which explains why I get no branches:

```
git pull origin dev
remote: Counting objects: 7957, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2572/2572), done.
remote: Total 7957 (delta 5300), reused 7841 (delta 5237)
Receiving objects: 100% (7957/7957), 20.40 MiB | 22.63 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5300/5300), done.
From /var/www/DEV-SITE
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      dev        -> origin/dev
error: Untracked working tree file '.editorconfig' would be overwritten by merge.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and check what you current branch is with `git branch -avvv`

```
From /var/www/DEV-SITE
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      dev        -> origin/dev
```

If none is currently set, you can do a:

```
git checkout dev
```

That will automatically track `origin/dev` (imported by the `git fetch` part of the `git pull`) and switch to that branch content.

Make sure you don't have any modification specific to STAGING though: they would be overridden.

Comment: When I execute that command as you suggested I get information on all the branches on the DEV-SITE. I added some more information to my question which may help diagnose this issue

Answer (score 1):

The first pull from a remote needs the branch specified. I tend to do this in the format

`git pull <remote> <branch>`

so in your case this should be

`git pull origin master`

Comment: Thanks. I encountered a problem which I have detailed beneath my question

Comment: Right. In this case, you have a local file in your staging directory which has been changed. Is .editorconfig a file which is part of your website, or a file which was created by one of the tools you are using? If the latter, I would recommend deleting it and trying again. If the former, copy it out of the directory, delete it, do the pull, then copy it back in again.

Comment: Also, if one of us has helped you fix your problem, can you mark the problem as solved? It would be appreciated.